# Using Box.V2 API, a DownloadStreamAsync call is resulting in corrupt file

Tags: c#, windows, box-api

I'm working on a small program to pull a file from a Box.com account. Using the Box C# SDK, I have the following code:

```
BoxFile file = await Client.FilesManager.GetInformationAsync(item.Id);
byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Size.Value];  

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
using (Stream stream = await Client.FilesManager.DownloadStreamAsync(file.Id))
{   
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Size.Value);
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

However, when I try to pull an image the resulting file is an image with the correct width and height but only a top slice has pixel data. The remainder of the image is black. The file size is correct.

If I pull a docx or pptx file and open them in Word or PowerPoint I get a corrupt file message. The file size is correct.

If the file is a simple txt file, it seems to be successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use CopyTo on your stream. Try stream.CopyTo(fileStream). Are you sure the number of bytes read from the stream is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stream` will make the content available in chunks as data is returned from the server. The single `stream.Read` call is only fetching the first chunk, which is why the top slice of the image appears correct but the rest of the image is empty.

To resolve this, continue reading from the stream until it indicates that there is no additional content.

```
using (Stream stream = await Client.FilesManager.DownloadStreamAsync(file.Id))
{   
   int bytesRead;
   var buffer = new byte[8192];
   do
   {
       bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
       await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   } while (bytesRead > 0);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's working! Thanks. Is 8192 an expected chunk size? Where did that number come from?

Comment: 8192 is just a 4K-aligned power of two. Feel free to use a different value, but I'd stick to that pattern. The `stream.ReadAsync` will read *at most* the length of the buffer in any one operation. In verifying the answer I gave you I'd see 4096- and 8192-byte reads, which suggests that the operation prefers 4K-aligned buffers.